# Does there exist a non-commutative, non-pure, non-group monoid such that its set of invertible elements commutes with every element?

Tags: abstract-algebra, monoid

Does there exist a non-commutative monoid $(M,*)$, which is not a group, and which is also not pure, meaning it has at least one non-identity invertible element, such that the set of invertible elements $U$ of $M$ commutes under multiplication with every element $a$ of $M$, in symbols: $a*U = U*a$? Of course, if $M$ is commutative, or a group, or pure, then certainly $U$ commutes under multiplication with every element $a$ of $M$. Hence, I am looking for a non-trivial example of that phenomenon. This question was inspired by a text I read online.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take the direct product $A \times N$ of a nontrivial abelian group $A$ and a noncommutative pure monoid $N$, e.g. $\mathbb{Z}$ times the free monoid on $2$ generators. By construction the group of units is $A$ and by construction it commutes (even pointwise, which is stronger than what you asked for) with everything.

Comment: If $M$ is a group, then $U=M$ and the set $a*M=M*a=M$, for every element $a \in M$.

Comment: Ah, I misread your notation, my bad; you only wanted it to commute setwise rather than pointwise? Well, as you can see, we can get pointwise anyway.

Comment: Another example, which I just thought of, is the quaternions $\mathbb{H}$, including $0$, under multiplication. It is technically not a group, because $0$ does not have an inverse, it is not commutative, and it is not pure. But the set of invertibles is the non-zero quaternions, which does commute setwise with every quaternion.

Comment: Also, is there a finite example of such a monoid?

Comment: @user107952: I assume you mean a finite example for $N$, a noncommutative pure monoid. This is a bit clunky but it works: start with the free monoid on $2$ generators, adjoin a zero element, and then quotient by relations setting every word of length $\ge 3$ to zero.